# Decode EncodeURIComponet using java

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, encodeuricomponent

I am passing values to server using `encodeURIComponent` through an AJAX call, but on the server side `request.getParameter()` is not decoding it automatically. How can I decode the value? I am using spring MVC.

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    url: "test/editTest.do",
    data: "id=" + encodeURIComponent(id)
})
```

Any help and guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a charset filter as a first filter in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, you can make sure that your server is configured properly, for tomcat for instance adding URIEncoding to connector

```
<connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

will specify the character encoding used to decode the URI. If you're not using tomcat you should find an equivalent for your server

Comment: thanks for you quick response..I have already used these but..It does'nt help

Comment: I've edited an answer with another suggestion, ajax request adds UTF-8 by default, so it could be the server configuration that is faling. Where do you see that the data are not decoded properly, logs? DB?

Comment: I have used like you said the value am getting in server side is in encoded form

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following in Java:

```
URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("id").replace("+", "%2B"), "UTF-8").replace("%2B", "+");
```

This should simulate `decodeURIComponent` on Java end. Java's URLDecoder decodes the plus sign to a space and hence the replace functions.

Comment: @AirCool thanks for answer..It works fine..but I am passing such request from multiple ajax calls and i want to handle all the calls in multiple actions...so using this method is not standard way I think..I need some thing like Master slave said.sadly it is not working well.. :(

Comment: Well, in that case, you can use a `Filter` on Java end and ensure that each request is intercepted through the filter. Within the filter you can modify the request param value through this method. Would that work?

Comment: I have read that when using the GET method no decoding is necessary.So using POST method there is no build-in functions are there to solve this issue,it seems..The suggestion u were said has the good but could you please explain it well.I am totally new bee to this

Comment: Read about how to apply filters:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html

www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-filter-and-how-do-i-use-it.html

Comment: @aircool thanks..I finally found problem is with my datatTable paramters.. I pass aoData.push({"name":"Id", "value":encodeURIComponent(Id)})..This id is not decoding automatically in controller..What i can i do for this..encoded paramters through ajax calls working fine